# How to make mysql attendace report base on workday calendar table join with employee attendance table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make report for human resource that show employee attendance for 1 moth period, and i already have 1 table that store workday in current month.

my table workday show like this :

```
    date
    2019-01-01
    2019-01-02
    2019-01-03
    2019-01-04
    ...
    2019-01-31
```

then i need join table above with my log_absen table, which show like this

```
emp_id .       date . tap_in
0001     2019-01-01 . 09:00
0001     2019-01-02 . 09:00
0002     2019-01-01 . 09:00
```

and then the show i expected is :

```
date       emp_id    status
2019-01-01  0001     Present
2019-02-01  0002     Present
2019-02-02  0001     Present
2019-02-02  0002     Alpha
2019-02-03  0001     Alpha
2019-02-03  0002     Alpha
2019-02-04  0001     Alpha  
2019-02-04  0002     Alpha 
etc ...
2019-02-31  0001     Alpha
```

is there any way to do this in mysql ?
thanks for any help's

Comment: Hi. Does `log_absen` store only date when the employee was in the work? If you you need to use `RIGHT JOIN` to select all the dates from `date` and pair it with data from`log_absen`

Comment: hallo, @DamianDziaduch yes, log_absen only store when user was in the work , could you give me the sql example code ? thank's

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the data set and the result set

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> Innerjoin function

Like this

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```